# Blender .obj files incredibly small in Unreal Engine 4

Tags: 3d, blender, modeling, unreal-engine4

I'm playing around with Unreal Engine 4 and Blender, mainly to learn how to make 3D models.  I'm attempting to use a singular flat plane as an obj file to be a sort of ground in ue4.  However whenever I import the file, it comes out ridiculously small (smaller than the first person character I'm using.).  I tried enlarging it but I get the same result.  Any ideas why?

Comment: @tkausl I thought I was using the resize tool and actually affecting the object itself.  If the resize doesn't do that, then what will?

Comment: Have you set up the coordinate system correctly? [Blender.SE](http://blender.stackexchange.com/) or [GameDevelopment.SE](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) might know whats the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you are importing an fbx file, you can change lot of things in static mesh editor window. For example you can redefine boundaries, change used materials ets. 
So, in (I believe) **Defaults**, you need to find **Transform** section and then redefine Import uniform scale. And if I remember it correctly, you can also set this scale right after you select imported mesh, in additional import settings dialog.

Also, when you have mouse hover on imported file in Content window (and it is definitely in static mesh editor window), you can see approximate size of that object in UE units. So scale coeficient is then only a simple math.

You can find more [here](https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/191567/resize-a-mesh-within-project.html).

Answer (score 0):

If the in-game size doesn't change when you change it in blender, try "Object/Apply/Scale" in Blender.
If you don't have a specific reason not to, you should apply all transforms before exporting.